# Railo(4.1) spreadsheet reading issue

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I am using railo server 4.1 and also installed the extension provider for spreadsheet support (http://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/RailoExtensionProvider/ExtensionProvider.cfc). But I can't able to read the spreadsheet using cfspreadsheet Am I missing something? or else provide any alternate solution.

The following is the error produced when i run a cfm page with cfspreadsheet tag in it

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#expandPath('..\')#/TEST.xls" query="res">
<cfdump var="#res#" />
```

[image: This the error causing when i run a cfm page with cfspreadsheet tag in it]

Comment: Yes you are missing something.  You are missing a description of your attempt and the ensuing result.

Comment: I suggest getting in touch with Andy Jarrett for help with his code. This is really nothing to do with Railo or ColdFusion (esp. as you're not even running it on ColdFusion!)

Comment: You're also missing your your actual code. So we have a fighting chance of knowing what's being passed as `arguments.rc` and `arguments.query`. Recommend you read this: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html, and then revise your approach to troubleshooting, and what you present in your question accordingly. Then we can possibly help.

Comment: My guess from looking at the posted code and error is that for whatever reason the "src" attribute is not resolving to something that the extension sees as a valid path.  To eliminate this possibility, try with a hard-coded path.